# Vue's `<router-link>` doesn't work when passed in data template literals?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I passed `<router-link>` with `${...}` for **home** page and without `${...}` for **log in** page, but none works when passed in template.

```js
data(){
  return {
    content: `
        <p>Click ${<router-link to="{name: 'home'}">homepage</router-link>} 
        or <router-link to="/login">login</router-link> to proceed.</p>`
  },
}
```

passing the data in templates:

```html
<h2 v-html="item.content"></h2>
```

and the output is:

[image]

and this's how it looks in console:

[image]

Can anyone help so it works as `a` links and go to the route? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `<p>Click <router-link to="{name: 'home'}">homepage</router-link> or <router-link to="/login">login</router-link> to proceed.</p>` ?

Comment: because the object you see is in an array of 100 objects, looping through them is easier than hardcoding it like above

Comment: You should describe this in your original question because the way the question is written is not very clear what are your end goals

Comment: You should use a render function - not a template. The render functions were invented exactly for this kind of job.